# Can JAVA not get the physical address of file in the disk?

Tags: java

There are memory limit in the JVM.If i want to read a big file like the size greater than 1GB and save it to the other location in this situation that can't change the JVM's virtual memory.

Comment: No, Java does not have a swap mechanism. However, your Operating System almost certainly does. Finally, there is no reason to read a big file into memory for saving it to another location.

Comment: You should rephrase your question - it is at variance with the body of the question. Are you asking about a file location, the JVM memory limits or something else?

Comment: Use [`Files.copy`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#copy-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-) or [`Files.move`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-).

Answer (score 1):

Time to read the docs on [`Files.move()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#move-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.Path-java.nio.file.CopyOption...-). You don't need to read the file into memory...

> Alternatively, suppose we want to move a file to new directory,
>   keeping the same file name, and replacing any existing file of that
>   name in the directory:

```
Path source = ...
Path newdir = ...
Files.move(source, newdir.resolve(source.getFileName()), REPLACE_EXISTING);
```

**Parameters:**

> source

```
the path to the file to move target - the path to the target file (may be associated with a different provider to the source path)
```

> options

```
options specifying how the move should be done
```

**Returns**

```
the path to the target file
```